# su: setgid failed: Operation not permitted error in aosp

Tags: android, android-source

aosp version android-8.1.0_r18
phone nexus5x
eng system
My app is system signature
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14J5i.png)

There is no problem in the shell

```
# adb shell
# getenforce selinux status is disabled
Permissive
# su system
$ su
```

no anything error

permission description of su

```
-rwsrwsrwx 1 root shell 11080 2021-06-07 17:14 /system/xbin/su
```

and i modified su.cpp

```
    if (current_uid != AID_ROOT && current_uid != AID_SHELL && current_uid != AID_SYSTEM) error(1, 0, "not allowed");
```

app code

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
                BufferedReader resultReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
                BufferedReader errorReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
                result = new StringBuffer();
                error = new StringBuffer();
                DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
                process.waitFor();
                String line;
                while ((line = resultReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    line += "\n";
                    result.append(line);
                    Log.d("AC", line);
                }

                resultReader.close();

                while ((line = errorReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    line += "\n";
                    error.append(line);
                    Log.e("AC", "exec err：" + line);
                }
```

i get su: setgid failed: Operation not permitted err

Comment: It may be blocked by sepolicy. Try to find avc:denied in kernel log: adb shell su root dmesg | grep 'avc: '.   https://source.android.com/security/selinux/validate#reading_denials

Comment: @Yong
selinux disable 
# getenforce                                                                                                                                                                                    
Permissive

Comment: It seems that it missed CAP_SETGID, while the shell process has this capabilities. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html

Comment: @user10357064 were you able to find anything ? I am also stuck at this.

Answer (score 0):

@Yong  i set cap_setgid capability of su file, run app i get
`java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "su": error=1, Operation not permitted`

```
bullhead:/ # getcap /system/xbin/su                                                                                                                                                                        
/system/xbin/su = cap_setgid+eip
bullhead:/ #
```